# Proper use of variable names

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables

This is a purely theoretical question:

I have a class that has a variable: **varX**.
I have a method that changes this variable. Xcode, with autocompletion suggest:

```
-(void)setVarX:(float)varX;
```

In implementation, when I write the instance method, Xcode tells me a warning:

> "Local declaration of 'varX' Hides instance variable"

the method:

```
-(void)setVarX:(float)varX {

    varX = varX;

}
```

So, to solve, I used the underscore in synthesize;

```
@synthesize varX = _varX;
```

and the method is:

```
-(void)setVarX:(float)varX {

    _varX = varX;

}
```

is proper to use the underscore before variables in this way? otherwise how do I use the name of the method suggested by Xcode?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.4 (and later) have automatic synthesis of properties (so that `@synthesize` is not needed anymore) when you don't use `@dynamic`. The automatic synthesis uses the underscore, so it seems that Apple wants this to be a convention.

First, I disliked this idea, but now I see why it's handy. Those variable names of those properties aren't "reserved" anymore in more methods (I never use underscores in other situations).

Answer (score 2):

Using `_varX` is the right approach. If you leave out the `@synthesize` line (as of Xcode 4.4) it will automatically generate an instance variable with that name.

Comment: I was wondering why XCode 4.4 hadn't been doing the "auto-synthesize" it was supposed to. Forgot about the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Note that changing the instance variable name effectively changes the class, while changing the method argument name does not.

Therefore I prefer to do it the other way around:

-(void)setVarX:(float)_varX {

```
varX = _varX;
```

}

so that the instance variable name, which is part of the class externally visible interface, does not need to be changed.